# Filtering two py2store stores with the same set of keys

Tags: python, key, store, filtered

In the following code, based on an example I found using [py2store](https://github.com/i2mint/py2store), I use `with_key_filt` to make two daccs (one with train data, the other with test data). I do get a filtered `annots` store, but the `wfs` store is not filtered.
What am I doing wrong?

```
from py2store import cached_keys

class Dacc:
    """Waveform and annotation data access"""
    def __init__(self, wfs, annots, annot_to_tag=lambda x: x['tag']):
        self.wfs = wfs  # waveform store  (keys: filepaths, values: numpy arrays)
        self.annots = annots  # annotation store (keys: filepaths, values: dicts or pandas series)
        self.annot_to_tag = annot_to_tag  # function to compute a tag from an annotation item

    @classmethod
    def with_key_filt(cls, key_filt, wfs, annots, annot_to_tag, chunker):
        """
        Make an instance of the dacc class where the data is filtered out.
        You could also filter out externaly, but this can be convenient
        """
        filtered_annots = cached_keys(annots, keys_cache=key_filt)
        return cls(wfs, filtered_annots, annot_to_tag)

    def wf_tag_gen(self):
        """Generator of (wf, tag) tuples"""
        for k in self.annots:
            try:
                wf = self.wfs[k]
                annot = self.annots[k]
                yield wf, self.annot_to_tag(annot)
            except KeyError:
                pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the intent of `with_key_filt` seems to be to filter `annots`, which itself is used as the seed of the `wg_tag_gen` generator (and probably the other generators you didn't post). As such, it does indeed filter everything.

But I do agree on your expectation that the `wfs` should be filtered as well. To achieve this, you just need to add one line to filter the `wfs`.

```py
class TheDaccYouWant(Dacc):
    @classmethod
    def with_key_filt(cls, key_filt, wfs, annots, annot_to_tag, chunker):
        filtered_annots = cached_keys(annots, keys_cache=key_filt)
        wfs = cached_keys(wfs, keys_cache=key_filt)  # here's what was added
        return cls(wfs, filtered_annots, annot_to_tag, chunker)
```